# Constructing image in python after 2D-fft

Tags: python, image, image-processing, signal-processing, fft

Recently I did my own 2d-fft to get the frequency spectrum from 512x512 image, using python. I did the 2d-fft using 1d-fft, by doing the 1d on every row, and then on every column I ended up having a 512x512 matrix of complex numbers.

I want to know how can I construct the resulting image from this complex array? Should I use the real values only? Or should I convert the real and imaginary to magnitude and phase, and then use the magnitude to build up my resulting image?

Comment: It's up to you. There is no correct way. Usually you would combine the result with another fft then inverse-fft it (convolution), and the result should have near-zero imaginary values.

Comment: I mean how can I construct the image from a complex array ?? like how can I output the frequency spectrum image??

Comment: It's up to you. There is no correct way. For example, some software has a set of display options. Some common ones: magnitude only, magnitude is intensity, phase is colour, real and complex components in different channels, only magnitude/only phase displayed as separate images.

Comment: You don't need to do two 1-d ffts.  Just use `numpy.fft.fft2` or `scipy.fftpack.fft2` on a 2-d array.  Then decide what you want to display.  Usually, people are interested in either phase or magnitude.